# PayPal Standard Buttons vs JavaScriptButtons

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Recently I looked at the less onerous payment options using PayPal. And considering my knowledge thought of using the [Payments Standard Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/wp_standard_overview/#payment-buttons).

Follow the tutorial to create the signature buttons to my system, but particularly did not like having to be managing my buttons on the PayPal website. In this sense, I sought something more flexible and found the [PayPal JavaScriptButtons](https://github.com/paypal/JavaScriptButtons).

I was satisfied with the possibilities of JavaScriptButtons, though concerned about some aspects. For example, my Merchant ID, Product Amount and Currency will be exposed in my HTML. In this way, a user can edit the values of these fields through the Inspection Tool available in the browser, causing potential problems...

Finally, I would like the opinion of you with regard to best practices and possibilities in this scenario.
Already thanks!

Comment: _Any_ client-side "only" data exchange is susceptible to the concerns you stated. When you manage your buttons at Paypal they handle security for you so _you don't have to do it yourself_. You do have other options to [Secure Your PayPal Payments Standard Buttons](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/encryptedwebpayments/#id08A3I0MK05Z).